# Adding element to a vector (conj function) and keep changes

Tags: clojure

The goal of my function is to read the input *interpreting-vector* and return a value after analysis.

To archieve my goal I need to add a string to a vector and keep the changes.
The conj function return a new vector but doesn't change my variable **eq_code** actually.

*(conj eq_code (get-in vector [3 1]))* doesn't change the value of the vector **eq_code**. I don't think repeat a let function with the variable **eq_code** would solve my problem.

Here is a piece of my code :

```
(defn interpreted-lang-while [interpreting-vector]
  (let [vector interpreting-vector
    ;before_if code added to eq_code
    eq_code [(str (get-in vector [1 1]) "0;")]]


    (def interpret-eval-eq_code (->> (apply str eq_code) lang1-parser lang1-interpret)) 


    (while 
      ;eval the code (last value contains condition)
      (not= 0 (do (conj eq_code (str (get-in vector [2 1]) ";"))(interpret-eval-eq_code) (prn (str "Eval condition : " (apply str eq_code)))))
      ;if the last value is not 0 =>add the statement_OK and eval the condition again
      (do (conj eq_code (get-in vector [3 1])) (prn (str "End loop code : " (apply str eq_code)))))
     (conj vector (str (interpret-eval-eq_code) ";")) 

;last values contains 0 =>end of the while
(prn (str "Code equivalent : " eq_code)) 
(conj eq_code (get-in vector [4 1])) 
(interpret-eval-eq_code)))
```

I execute the following line with clojure :

```
 (interpreted-lang-while [:LangWHILE [:before_while "a=1; b= a+2; c="] [:condition_expression "a-3"] [:statements_OK "a=a+1;b=b+2;"] [:after_while " c+1;"]])
```

I get the following output on the terminal :

```
project.core=> "Eval condition : a=1; b= a+2; c=0;"
"End loop code : a=1; b= a+2; c=0;"
"Eval condition : a=1; b= a+2; c=0;"
"End loop code : a=1; b= a+2; c=0;"
"Eval condition : a=1; b= a+2; c=0;"
"End loop code : a=1; b= a+2; c=0;"
<Infinite loop ...>
```

Instead of

```
project.core=> "Eval condition : a=1; b= a+2; c=0;a-3;"
"End loop code : a=1; b= a+2; c=0;a-3;a=a+1;b=b+2;"
"Eval condition : a=1; b= a+2; c=0;a-3;a=a+1;b=b+2;a-3;"
<And so on ..>
```

Can you suggest me a way to add new element to my vector and changing my variable **eq_code**?
Thanks for your help.

Comment: You're trying to write imperative code, which Clojure is going to make very difficult. You shouldn't be trying to alter `eq_code`, or use `while` or `do`. Look into `loop` to create "modified" variables once per loop.

Comment: Go [here](https://clojure.org/about/functional_programming), and scroll down to "recursive looping". Functional programming requires thinking about code differently. It isn't about changing data (like trying to change `eq-code`), it's about producing new, modified data.

Comment: Thanks. I will try the loop function. I don't understand how I must use the (recur) function in my code. Should it be ?  (recur (eq_code (conj eq_code (get-in vector [3 1]))))

Comment: You give to `loop` the variable that you want to change once per loop (called the "accumulator"), and give to `recur` the modified version of the variable that you want to be passed on to the next loop. For your case here, it would be something like [this](https://gist.github.com/carcigenicate/d885b34a0a5a8f895cdfeb375d359f14) (created a gist for readability).

Comment: You might want to practice using `loop` and recursion on simpler examples before continuing on with your current project. From what you posted here, it looks like you're using to imperative programming. Switching to functional programming from that is going to change how you have to write code, and will take a bit of getting used to. Simple examples will make for better practice material.

Comment: Thanks for your example. I will do some practice

Comment: I finally succeed to change the value of 'eq_code' using 'loop' and 'recur'. Thanks all of you for your precious help !

Comment: Np. Glad you got it working. I'll note, if you ever *really do* need mutability, Clojure has constructs like `atom`s that allow for mutation, but they're entirely unnecessary for that vast majority of circumstances. They should really only be used for communication between threads (atoms are thread safe).

Comment: Oh, and as a final note, me and a few others here frequent the Code Review site here on the Stack Exchange network. If you post full, runnable code  (requirements of the site) there, we can suggest improvements to help you write better, more idiomatic code.